# Load information dynamically in Symfony2 form builder

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I am working with Symfony2. I have two fields in a form builder, when I select a choice in the first field, information in the second field should be reloaded dynamically according the first choice.

How can I do it ?

Comment: you can do this with ajax (Jquery ) , make an ajax request to some controller and make it return the info .. and with jquery fill that field .. this is how it's done (i dont think there is any other way ) if you want it to be dynamically

Comment: please read futher at http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks codiez, but i am a beginner in Symfony 2, can you explain it more please .

Answer (score 1):

**What do we need?**

Let's say for the sake of simplicity you need when the user type in 'knock knock' the next field is filled with 'who's there'.

Assuming that the first field (which the user will fill) has an id of `#input_filled_by_user` and the other field's id is `#input_filled_with_php`.

**How do we solve this?**

As long as the user will be typing after the script is executed, we need something to tell us the he wrote the specific word in or case 'knock knock' (which is jQuery), and send it to a controller (a fancy name for rest API).

And then in the controller we process and send back result, and with jQuery (again) we output the result to the user.

**The code**

First we need a router:

```
my_door_keeper_router:
    pattern:  /request/{string}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:door:keeper, _format: ~ }
requirements:
    _method: GET
    id: "\d+"
```

And here is the action controller:

```
public function keeperAction($string)
{

    if ($string == 'knock knock') {
        echo "hello"; // please dont do it with echo use symfony way , i just dont have enough time 
    }

    return;
}
```

Now with jQuery:

```
$('#input_filled_by_user').change(
   function(){
      $.get('/request', { string: $(this).val() } ,function(data) {
  $('#input_filled_with_php').val(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
   }
)
```

And that's it. Hope this makes sense (please dig deeper, I tried to explain it the dummy way, and some of the things i mentioned are half correct, but for whatever you're trying to do now you will be fine doing so).

Comment: Hi there. Good answer, but our Q&A format does place high value on presentation. So, if you can use some capital letters, it is much appreciated!